# VSTO mail sent event

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have a small problem with VSTO. I need to get the sent mail and persist the content of it. Is there a kind on MailSent event?

The only solution I found for now is hooking up the ItemAdd event on SentItems folder.

```
Outlook.Folder sentItems =
     Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
    as Outlook.Folder;
sentItems.Items.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(SentItemFolder_ItemAdd);

private void SentItemFolder_ItemAdd(object addedItem)
{
    Outlook.MailItem newItem = (Outlook.MailItem)addedItem;

    MessageBox.Show(newItem.EntryID);
}
```

Is this really the only way or any of you know any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ItemSend` event for this, like so:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
}


private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    // Code to run when item is being sent
}
```

Comment: Yes but then item is not yet sent. I was asking about ItemSent event. If you check the item that you get as a parameter, it is not yet sent and all the info's about sent time and similar are not yet ready. And also is not sad that the sending will be successful.

Comment: @MaiOM I don't know about any Sent event.  I see in blog articles that you are not the only one to use SentItems.ItemAdd to catch this, but actually I'd think that ItemSend is a better option.  The ItemSend event occurs when the email is being sent, so the "send time" is "now".  The mail will be added to "Sent items" even if the mail is never delivered (try sending a mail to a non-existent recipient).  Also, the user may turn off the feature to save sent items in that folder, by going to Tools->Options->E-Mail options

Comment: So when the item (ie. email/meeting request, say) post hitting Send in the UI, got queued in the outbox...? What then?

Comment: @deostroll I don't understand what you are asking about. Maybe you should post this as a separate question in the forum

Comment: @GTG say Outlook client is offline for some reason. When we send an email, or, a meeting request, it gets queued in the outbox, until the time the client comes back online...is there or are there some events we can hook into at this point?

Comment: @deostroll - I'm not sure. I suggest you ask that in the forum